# How many hundred/hundreds

Tags: meaning, difference

Is it at all possible in English to ask this?

> 1 How many **hundreds of dollars** did you get?
>
> 2 How many **hundred dollars** did you get?

I think 1 is wrong. 2 might be OK. If both are wrong, how else can it be expressed?

Comment: "It is worth hundreds of dollars." "How many hundred(s)?" Neither option sounds definitely wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should try to avoid either.  Instead of asking "how many hundred dollars did you get" you should ask "How many dollars did you get?" or (if you are in Australia or another country that uses dollars)  "How much money did you get."

The answer will be the same.  It would be a little unusual to ask the person to denominate the money in "hundreds of dollars".  For example it would be more natural to describe $4000 as "four thousand dollars" instead of "forty hundred dollars".

The exception might be if you are asking specifically about receiving money in the form of one hundred dollar bills.  You could then ask "How many hundred dollar bills did you get?"  But a person could still receive thousands of dollars in 10-dollar bills and truthfully answer "none".

If for some reason you do need to use "how many hundred", you could use either "Hundred" or "hundreds", though I tend to prefer "how many hundred dollars did you get?"

Answer (score 1):

I think 2 might be used in casual speech. Normally, though, you would just ask  "how many dollars," and allow the person being questioned to respond in the hundreds if they so choose.